# New UUID and UDID generated each time I launch app in Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've got an app that grabs the UDID in `viewDidLoad()` for my initial `ViewController`:

```
var user = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString
```

This identifier is subsequently used to make a child node in Firebase. Testing this with Xcode's simulator, I find that I'm getting a new UDID every time I (1) build the app, or (2) force quit the app and relaunch from the home screen. I've been building for the same device (iPhone 5s) every time.

As a test, I redefined `var user` as:

```
var user = NSUUID().UUIDString
```

and I'm getting the same issue. New child nodes getting created with new IDs too often. Is this expected behavior for Simulator, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: that is not an issue, it should work like that, you need to test on a device if you want stable UUID

Comment: `var user = NSUUID().UUIDString`. UUIDs are meant to be random. Each time you create one, it will be different.

Comment: *only after generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for the next 100 years, the probability of creating just one duplicate would be about 50%* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier